# how to save form ui component magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">edit_listing.sinhvien_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">edit_listing.sinhvien_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">edit_listing</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SAVE</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">hai/post/save</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="sinhvien_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Wsoftpro\Hai\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sinhvien_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="employee_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
            <field name="maSV">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> MaSV</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">post</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">maSV</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="hoten">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> hoten</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">data</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">hoten</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="ngaysinh">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> ngaysinh</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sv</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">ngaysinh</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: ,A Ui component related  with model and resource mode and collection and a table  you have to build it  first then you have to do UI component form